# CodeIgniter 3 and Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, codeigniter-3

I have a view and with this code in the head.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

and the following HTML:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal hide" role="dialog">
 </div>
```

The controller has:

```
 class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->library('session');

    }

    public function index() {
       $this->load->view('home');
    }

 }
```

When I run the view the modal does not appear. I am new CodeIgniter and do not understand why the modal does not work by simply running the `index.php/home`.

I am loading the `bootstrap.js` file in the footer in the correct order with jQuery. I have a Bootstrap alert working.

**Is there a Library or Helper that has to be loaded in the controller?**

Comment: well, why are you using `BootstrapDialog.alert('I want banana!');` ? where did you get this information from? if so what documentations are you using?

Comment: this is not a function that comes with javascript or jquery, you need a library. Please let us know what library you are using, and how you are loading it

Comment: Whoops my bad.  The line should be $('#myModal').modal('show'); There is a <div id="myModal" class="modal hide" role="dialog">.  Ultimately I am trying to get a modal to appear which I will pass data to when the user needs to supply more data.  Right now I can not get the modals to open.  I got the alerts working.

Comment: are you loading bootstrap? you need to provide your actual code. Please update your original post with all the code needed in order for us to guide you

Comment: JavaScript does not care anything about your framework.  It does not matter if you're using CodeIgniter or ASP.

Comment: ah ha!!! I figured out the problem.  I had my jquery.js loading in the common footer before the bootstrap.js. I had to move it to the common header.  It seems when you are trying to learn something new the simplest things can be staring you in the face and you can not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any html or body tags on your view. Also not really to do any thing with codeigniter it self.

**Here is script for auto show bootstrap on page load**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

**And The View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: ah ha!!! I figured out the problem.  I had my jquery.js loading in the common footer before the bootstrap.js. I had to move it to the common header.  It seems when you are trying to learn something new the simplest things can be staring you in the face and you can not see it.

Comment: It use to be the case where you add the jquery down bottom but I find now it works if have the Google jquery at top